# mysql get average data for full months

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following sample data:

**tblData**

```
Date           Sales
----------------------
2011-12-01       122
2011-12-02       433
2011-12-03       213
...
2011-12-31       235

2011-11-01       122
2011-11-02       433
2011-11-03       213
...
2011-11-30       235

2011-10-10       122
2011-10-11       433
2011-10-12       213
...
2011-10-31       235
```

Notice that October data begins at 10 October, whereas subsequent months have complete data.

I need to get the average monthly sales over all complete months, which in this case would be November and December 2011.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT `date`, AVG(`sales`)
FROM sales
GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)
HAVING COUNT(`date`) = DAY(LAST_DAY(`date`));
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbb02/1)

If you want to limit the result, either

```
HAVING ...
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 3
```

which should always return data for the 3 most recent months, or something like

```
FROM ...
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, '%Y-%m')
   <= DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m')
GROUP BY ...
```

which should return data for the 3 previous months, if there is any. I'm not sure which is better but I don't believe `WHERE` gets to use any index on `date`, and if you're using `DATETIME` and don't format it you'll also be comparing the days and you don't want that,

Comment: Thanks Quail. Out of interest, how would that change if I only wanted the last THREE complete months, rather than ALL complete months?

Comment: I know this is very old, but first of thanks for the answer It helped me with a small tweak :) 

`SELECT date,  AVG(sales)
FROM sales
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)`

By **removing** that last line `HAVING COUNT(date) = DAY(LAST_DAY(date));` I was able to calculate the average based on the seperate months despite my data also not having the full months filled in.  I'm not 100% sure why that is, but maybe this will help someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't test it right now, but please have a try with this one:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%Y-%m') AS yearMonth,
    SUM(Sales)
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY 
    yearMonth
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = DAY(LAST_DAY(`Date`)
```

Comment: You have a wrong group by - he needs monthly average. Grouping by just `Date` will give you daily average.

Comment: You can not access column as aliases in GROUP BY. Consider either `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%Y-%m')` which is suboptimal or `GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)` as Quail suggest in his answer

Comment: @ZaarHai In MySQL you can, it's totally fine. And in my opinion it's much more eye friendly, meaning easier to read.

Comment: You are right. Still I think that `group by year(), month()` is better performance-wise.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no measurable difference.